# path corridor calculation

Tags: line, route

I have a route/path in my map that I need to draw a "corridor" on. Basically, the corridor are parallel lines on the route with a given distance in nautical miles.

The red line is the route, the blue line is the corridor.

I have the idea of making a radius with the given distance on each waypoint in the map and from there I would draw a line from the edges of the circles. So I was wondering if there is any official approach or calculation to this?

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I will not really be using a GIS software to plot the corridor lines. The screenshot above is made using Scribble Maps for example. I will be drawing the line on an iOS application using WhirlyGlobe library. In the iOS app, I will need to plot the points of the corridor lines and it will draw the line it self.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to include that important information in your question.